# Swift: safely get character at index

Tags: string, swift

Using built in methods, one can access the element at index i of a string by using:

```
let s = "string" 
s[advance(s.startIndex,i)]
```

However, if `i` is out of range this results in a runtime error. Is there a built in way to achieve this and get it to return `nil` if the index is out of range? Seeing as optional chaining exists for just about everything, I'd expect this to be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is – there’s a second version of advance that takes a third parameter, an index not to go beyond:

```
let s = "string"
let idx = advance(s.startIndex, i, s.endIndex)
```

Unfortunately it’s a bit more fiddly than your hoped-for usage.  If you do this:

```
let s = "string"
let idx = advance(s.startIndex, 10, s.endIndex)
```

then you’ll still get a runtime error, because `endIndex` isn’t a valid index for subscript.

You have two choices, both of which involve an extra check.  Either check `idx != s.endIndex`.  Or check `!s.isEmpty` then if not, do `s[advance(s.startIndex, i, s.endIndex.predecessor())]`.

(you have to check the string isn’t empty here for two reasons – one is if it is, no subscript is valid, and the other is if `startIndex == endIndex` then `endIndex.predecessor()` isn’t valid)

Finally, beware putting calls to `advance` from `startIndex` like this in a loop.  `advance` from a point is not a constant-time operation, it’s linear.  So if you call it in a loop over the string length, your algorithm will be quadratic.  If you need to walk the string, best to do it by continuously incrementing an index or even better using a higher-level function like `map` or `filter`.